# Azure App Service Custom Domain - website functions differently

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We've deployed our .NET Core 2.2/Angular 6 website to an Azure App Service with default URL of `abcxyz.azurewebsites.net`.

We added a custom domain of `users.contoso.com` to the app service by adding a CNAME record for users to our `contoso.com` domain, and pointing it at `abcxyz.azurewebsites.net` and then adding `users.contoso.com` to the Custom Domains section of the App Service in the Azure portal.

Now, browsing to `users.contoso.com` *does* bring up the login page of the website, but that's where the functionality stops.  The formatting is not the same as if you browse to `abcxyz.azurewebsites.net`, and attempting to login does nothing.  Further, certain logos on the login page are replaced with the word "logo".

Everything looks and functions as expected when using the site at `abcxyz.azurewebsites.net`.

Obviously there are other steps I need to take that I haven't taken - does something also have to be updated in the source code?  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: So no broken links or errors when looking in the browser's dev tools?

Comment: What about clear the cache in your web browser?

Comment: @Stpete111 you could add your solution in the answer.

Comment: @NancyXiong done, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We discovered that CORS was blocking the ability for the front-end to fully communicate with the API when using the site at the custom domain. We needed to add the custom domain to the CORS list. Hopefully this helps someone if it happens to them.